# Code coverage between master and dev branch

Tags: sonarqube

I want to be able to rebase my dev branch with master and still be able to get code coverage of only my changes. Is this possible in SonarQube? There is a plugin which will track changes between commits on a branch but once I rebase from master it will have changes in the dev branch which has nothing to do with the feature I am working on.

Is there a way to get "new code" statistics between what is in the master branch and what is in the dev branch after the dev branch has been rebased with master?